# Make table take full page width when printing

Tags: html, css

How could I make a table take full page width when printing? I've tried doing

```
@media print {
    table{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

and

```
@media print {
    table{
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: The latter should work; you may well have a style overriding the above.